# Can logistic regression be used when the dataset has observations from the same users but are unique per day

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, python, statsmodels

I have a dataset that captures user information by day (the users are unique per day but often have observations on multiple days) and I want to analyze a binary outcome.

Is there a more appropriate model than logistic regression or can I control for date or user?

How can I do so? This is what I have in Python as you can see the model fit is not ideal. I did not include user or date in my model.

```
model = smf.logit('flag~C(variable1)+variable2+variable3+C(variable4)',data=df).fit()


Logit Regression Results
Dep. Variable:  cflag   No. Observations:   1402311
Model:  Logit   Df Residuals:   1402304
Method: MLE Df Model:   6
Date:   Fri, 02 Oct 2020    Pseudo R-squ.:  0.02904
Time:   13:39:03    Log-Likelihood: -5.6997e+05
converged:  True    LL-Null:    -5.8702e+05
Covariance Type:    nonrobust   LLR p-value:    0.000

``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple observations on the same individual then the assumption of independence among observations no longer holds. You *need* to control for `user` in that case. Whether you also control for `date` depends on your understanding of the subject matter.

For a logistic model that can be done with a [mixed-effects model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model), in which you keep track of the individual associated with each observation while some aspects of the model are allowed to vary among individuals. The simplest is modeling a *random* distribution of individual-specific intercepts that represent the log-odds at the (possibly hypothetical) baseline covariate conditions, while influences of covariates beyond the baseline are *fixed*, assumed to be the same for all individuals. The combination of random and fixed effects makes it a mixed-effects model. There are over 4000 threads on this site that are tagged [`mixed-model`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mixed-model).

If you think that there is a systematic change in the log-odds of an outcome over time, then you could add a measure of that time as a predictor. Depending on the nature of your data, you might better handle event occurrence over time with a survival model.